# Proof of uniqueness of a fixed point

Tags: functional-analysis

The Banach fixed point theorem:

Let $(X,d)$ be a complete metric space and $$f: X \to X$$ be a contractive map then there is a unique fixed point.

I am trying to prove the uniqueness of a fixed point.

This is the proof: 
Assume that $x_1,x_2$ are two distinct fixed points.
Then $$0<d(x_1,x_2)=d(f(x_1), f(x_2)) \leq c.d(x_1,x_2) < d(x_1,x_2)$$

I understand that a contractive map satisfies $d(f(x),f(y)) \leq c.d(x,y)$
where $x,y \in X$ and constant $c \in (0,1)$.

> In the proof how can we say that $c\cdot d(x_1,x_2) < d(x_1,x_2)$?

The proof finishes of by saying

So $d(x_1,x_2)=0$ and so $x_1=x_2$.

How can we deduce this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can say that $c\,d(x_1,x_2)<d(x_1,x_2)$ because for a contraction map, $c<1$, and you have assumed that $x_1\neq x_2$. You have that $d(x_1,x_2)<d(x_1,x_2)$, a clear contradiction to your assumption that the points $x_1$ and $x_2$ are distinct. Therefore, $x_1=x_2$.

Answer (score 1):

This is true because $c<1$. The fact that $d(y,x)=0$ implies  $x=y$ is one of the defining properties of a metric.

Comment: You might also address the last point of the Question, why does $d(x_1,x_2) = 0$ imply $x_1=x_2$?